# Ckeditor usage in Ember

Tags: ember.js, ckeditor

I want to use CKEditor with my Ember app.
I am 100% a n00b with Ember, but I'm getting there.

I have tried my darndest to figure this out, but I've gotten nowhere :(

I have tried to use `ember-ckeditor`.  This ended up with the editor throwing a bunch of `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` errors for things such as config.js and other "assets" it expected to find in the assets folder.

I have tried `ember-cli-ckeditor`.  Same exact issues as above.

These two addons have pretty lame documentation.  For example, I have no idea how provide a custom config file, CSS, etc.  Or what if I want to use CkFinder?

The two above addons also throw some depreciated warnings when loading up the server, but I disgress....

I finally tried to manually include ckeditor v4.5.6 in the `vendor` folder.
I then included in `ember-cli-build.js` as such: `app.import('vendor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js');`
I'm not sure if I'm correct in doing this, and if so, how do I include use the editor plugin within my controller or component?

`CKEDITOR.replace("content");` as per usual outside of Ember?

Please school me!

Answer (score 4):

To use ckeditor without addons (creating your own component):

1. Install ckeditor using bower:

   ```
   bower install ckeditor --save
   ```
2. Install [broccoli-funnel](https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#using-broccoli-funnel), you will need it for ckeditor's assets:

   ```
   npm install broccoli-funnel --save-dev
   ```
3. In your ember-cli-build.js:

   At the top of file requere funnel

   ```
   var Funnel = require('broccoli-funnel');
   ```

   In app's options exclude ckeditor's assets from fingerprinting:

   ```
   var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
     fingerprint: {
       exclude: ['assets/ckeditor/']
     }
   });
   ```

   Import ckeditor's js and assets:

   ```
   app.import('bower_components/ckeditor/ckeditor.js');

   var ckeditorAssets = new Funnel('bower_components/ckeditor', {
     srcDir: '/',
     destDir: '/assets/ckeditor'
   });

   /**
    * If you need to use custom skin, put it into 
    * vendor/ckeditor/skins/<skin_name>
    * Also, custom plugins may be added in this way 
    * (look ckeditor's info for details)
    * If you don't need custom skins, you may remove
    * ckeditorCustoms
    */
   var ckeditorCustoms = new Funnel('vendor/ckeditor', {
     srcDir: '/',
     destDir: '/assets/ckeditor'
   });

   return app.toTree([ckeditorAssets, ckeditorCustoms]);
   ```
4. If your app is not in website's root, you may need to put this script in body section of index.html, before other scripts:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     window.CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '/path-to/assets/ckeditor/';
   </script>
   ```
5. Create a component. **Warning: this is a code from my abandoned pet project, and I'm 99% sure that it will not work for you "as is" because of missing dependencies and because it was created for different html layout. But I think it may help anyway. If you wish to try and copy-paste it, here are dependencies:**

   ```
   npm install --save-dev ember-browserify
   npm install --save-dev sanitize-html
   ```

   Component's code:

   ```
   /* globals CKEDITOR */
   import Ember from 'ember';
   import layout from '../templates/components/md-ckeditor'; //component's name!
   import SanitizeHTML from 'npm:sanitize-html';

   export default Ember.Component.extend({
     layout: layout,
     classNames: ['input-field'],

     _editor: null,

     bindAttributes: ['disabled', 'readonly', 'autofocus'],
     validate: false,

     errorsPath: 'errors',

     init() {
       this._super(...arguments);
       const propertyPath = this.get('valueBinding._label');
       if (Ember.isPresent(propertyPath)) {
         Ember.Binding.from(`targetObject.${this.get('errorsPath')}.${propertyPath}`)
           .to('errors')
           .connect(this);
       }
     },

     didInsertElement() {
       var i18n = this.get('i18n');

       if (Ember.isPresent(this.get('icon'))) {
         this.$('> span').css('padding-left', '3rem');
       }

       this._setupLabel();

       this._editor = CKEDITOR.inline(this.element.querySelector('.ckeditor'), {
         skin: 'minimalist',
         toolbar: [
           ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord'],
           ['Undo', 'Redo'],
           ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Strike'],
           ['Link', 'Unlink'],
           ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', 'Blockquote'],
           ['Source']
         ],
         linkShowAdvancedTab: false,
         linkShowTargetTab: false,
         language: i18n.get('locale'),
         removePlugins: 'elementspath'
       });
       this._editor.on('instanceReady', (e) => {
         this._updateValidClass();
       });
       this._editor.on('change', (e) => {
         this.set('value', e.editor.getData());
       });
       this._editor.on('focus', (e) => {
         var label = this.$('> label, > i');
         label.addClass('active');
       });
       this._editor.on('blur', (e) => {
         var label = this.$('> label, > i');
         var text  = SanitizeHTML(e.editor.getData(), {
           allowedTags: []
         }).trim();
         if (text !== '') {
           label.addClass('active');
         } else {
           label.removeClass('active');
         }
       });
     },

     willDestroyElement()
     {
       this._editor.destroy();
       this._editor = null;
     },        

     id: Ember.computed('elementId', function () {
       return `${this.get('elementId')}-input`;
     }),

     validClass: Ember.computed('value', 'errors', function () {
       var errors = this.get('errors');
       if (errors && errors.get && errors.get('firstObject')) {
         return 'invalid';
       } else if (!!this.get('value')) {
         return 'valid';
       } else {
         return '';
       }
     }),

     validClassChanged: Ember.observer('validClass', function () {
       Ember.run.once(this, '_updateValidClass');
     }),

     _updateValidClass() {
       if (this._editor && this._editor.container &&         this._editor.container.$) {
         Ember.$(this._editor.container.$).removeClass('invalid         valid').addClass(this.get('validClass'));
       }
     },

     _setupLabel() {
       const label = this.$('> label, > i');
       if (Ember.isPresent(this.get('value'))) {
         label.addClass('active');
       }
     }
   });
   ```

   Template:

   ```
   {{textarea
   id=id
   value=value
   name=name
   required=required
   readonly=readonly
   disabled=disabled
   maxlength=maxlength
   class="materialize-textarea ckeditor"
   classNameBindings="validate:validate: validClass"
   }}
   <label for="{{id}}">{{label}}</label>
   <small class="red-text">
        {{#if errors}} {{errors.firstObject}} {{else}} &nbsp; {{/if}}
   </small>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Check next example

https://github.com/ebryn/ember-ckeditor/blob/master/addon/components/ember-ckeditor.js

Or next package `ember-cli-ckeditor`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-ckeditor